# Remove duplicates (both lines) and duplicate only based on a sub-string

Tags: bash, duplicates, uniq

maybe someone can help me with the following problem.

I use:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -t} -k2 | less
```

The output contains duplicates when comparing starting from position 5 in line

```
A01} value1 = 5000000000
B01} value1 = 5000000000
A01} value2 = 6000000000
B01} value2 = 7000000000
```

How can I remove these both lines:

```
A01} value1 = 5000000000
B01} value1 = 5000000000
```

completely from my output?

The result should be:

```
A01} value2 = 6000000000
B01} value2 = 7000000000
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the unique values =?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to sort/uniq using the fields from key 2 (value) to key 4 (the number). So field 1 is skipped when invoking `uniq`:

```sh
cat file1 file2 |sort -k 2,4 |uniq --skip-fields=1 --unique
```

Comment: Didn't know about `--skip-fields`, this is a better answer than the one I gave below. My only concern is *if* this is a GNU only feature?

Comment: Yes this is a GNU/non-posix feature. I assumed the questioner is using a GNU system, because he used the `bash` tag

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
% grep -vFf <(cut -d'}' -f2 file.txt | sort | uniq -d) file.txt
A01} value2 = 6000000000
B01} value2 = 7000000000
```

This will create a "file" that contains all non unique lines:

```
cut -d'}' -f2 file.txt | sort | uniq -d
```

`<(...)` is a process substitution and works like this:

```
% echo <(ls)
/proc/self/fd/11
```

grep `-F` means plain text search, and `-f` expects a filename with keywords to search for. `-v` reverses the match.

And for multiply files you will need `-h` for suppressing filenames on matches:

```
grep -hvFf <(cut -d'}' -f2 a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq -d) a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: I think they are searching between two files (A values in file1, B values in file2), in which case you would probably want to put `... file1.txt file2.txt`.

Comment: Could probably just as simply add $(cat file1 file2) inplace of file.txt and that would call it a day -- Tried to use the backtick but this site hates backticks for some reason. lol

Comment: Yeah. multiple ways to do it actually... works either way.